# Copy Excel OneDrive table to an specific cell on another Excel OneDrive table (Power Automate)

Tags: onedrive, power-automate, excel-online, office-scripts

I need to copy data from one excel worksheet and paste (values only) on another worksheet using power automate + Office script

I started to creat a flow using the answer in the link bellow.

[Power Automate: Copy Excel OneDrive table to the bottom of another Excel OneDrive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967796/power-automate-copy-excel-onedrive-table-to-the-bottom-of-another-excel-onedriv)

The problem is I didnt understood the second script so I was not able to modify it to what I need ( that one paste on the end of the workbook)

SCRIPT on the link

```
For Run script I have

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const sheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[0];
  let lastRow = sheet.getUsedRange(true).getLastCell().getRowIndex() + 1;
  let rng = "A3:P" + lastRow
  let tableTest = sheet.getRange(rng).getValues();
  console.log(tableTest);
}
Then under Compose

@{outputs('Run_script')?['body']?['Logs'][0]}
Then Initialize the "RemoveString" variable

@{split(outputs('Compose'),' ')[0]}
Then Initialize the "NewString" variable

@{replace(outputs('Compose'),variables('RemoveString'),'')}
Then Run Script 2 and add "NewString" as the parameter.

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, rangeTest: string) {
  let table = workbook.getTable("BacklogTable");
  let str = rangeTest;
  let testerTest = JSON.parse(str);
  table.addRows(null, testerTest);
}
```

The reason for RemoveString is to remove the Date & Time Stamp from the outputs

Comment: Hey i answered that question, what did you want to do differently? Did you receive an error or something? Or did you want to add it to a cell that isn’t a table?

Comment: I know very little about office script but is not a problem if it is a table but I need the information to be paste on an specific cell and replace the information

Comment: Ok what cell do you want it to paste in?

Comment: Starting on A7 with range of previous copied table (paste as number)

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a little different workflow.

Run Script

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const sheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[0];
  let lastRow = sheet.getUsedRange(true).getLastCell().getRowIndex() + 1;
  let rng = "A2:C" + lastRow
  let tableTest = sheet.getRange(rng).getValues();
  console.log(tableTest);
  console.log(tableTest.length)
}
```

Compose

```
@{outputs('Run_script')?['body']?['Logs'][0]}
```

Compose 2

```
@{outputs('Run_script')?['body']?['Logs'][1]}
```

RemoveString

```
@{split(outputs('Compose'),' ')[0]}
```

NewString

```
@{replace(outputs('Compose'),variables('RemoveString'),'')}
```

RemoveString2

```
@{split(outputs('Compose_2'),' ')[0]}
```

NewString2

```
@{int(replace(outputs('Compose_2'),variables('RemoveString2'),''))}
```

Num

```
@{int(variables('NewString2'))}
```

Run Script 2

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, rangeTest: string, length: number) {
  let str = rangeTest;
  const arr = JSON.parse(str);
  let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
  let rng = "A7:C" + (6 + length); //Change C to whichever column you want to end on
  sheet.getRange(rng).setValues(arr);
  sheet.getRange(rng).setNumberFormatLocal("0.00");
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks !!! It sure answer my question ! I will try the flow this weekend and tell u if it worked  !

Answer (score 1):

I may not be following this correctly, but you can also return values and pass them to another connector in Power Automate. Here is some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/develop/power-automate-integration) on how to return values with Office Scripts. Also, below is an example script with parameters and a *number* type return value. With returning values rather than console.logging them, you won't need to remove any output in your Flow steps. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
function main(
  workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook,
  issueId: string,
  issueTitle: string): number {
  // Get the "GitHub" worksheet.
  let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("GitHub");

  // Get the first table in this worksheet, which contains the table of GitHub issues.
  let issueTable = worksheet.getTables()[0];

  // Add the issue ID and issue title as a row.
  issueTable.addRow(-1, [issueId, issueTitle]);

  // Return the number of rows in the table, which represents how many issues are assigned to this user.
  return issueTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
}
```